React Native iOS: "When In Use" Permission Grants "Always" Permission Automatically
I'm encountering an issue with location permissions in my React Native iOS app. When the permission prompt appears, I select "When In Use" for location access, but when I later check the "Always" permission, it's also granted, even though I never selected it.
Here's my code:
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    console.log('Requesting "When In Use" location permission for iOS...');
    const whenInUseStatus = await request(PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE);
    console.log('whenInUseStatus:', whenInUseStatus);

    if (whenInUseStatus === RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        // Checking for "Always" permission
        const alwaysStatus = await check(PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_ALWAYS);
        console.log('alwaysStatus:', alwaysStatus);

        if (alwaysStatus !== RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            Alert.alert(
                'Enable "Always" Location Access',
                'To provide a better experience, please enable "Always" location access in the app settings.',
                [
                    {
                        text: 'Go to Settings',
                        onPress: () => {
                            Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
                        },
                    },
                    { text: 'Cancel', style: 'cancel' },
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}

In Info.plist, I have these added:

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription

The popup shows the correct options for "When In Use", "Only Once" and "Never". However, when I select "When In Use", I’m finding that the app also gets the "Always" permission granted, which is not what I expect.
Has anyone faced a similar issue where selecting "When In Use" also grants the "Always" permission? Why might this be happening, and how can I ensure that "Always" is only granted when explicitly selected?
Any guidance would be appreciated!
I expected that when I selected "When In Use" location permission in the popup, only that permission would be granted. However, after selecting "When In Use", I checked the "Always" permission, and it was also granted, which is not what I expected. I tried checking the status of both permissions using request and check, but I’m still seeing this behavior.

If you are really only asking for 'when in use' then your app will not have "always" permissions. If your app is requesting "Always" permissions then the user will still see a "when in use" prompt but your app will receive "always" permissions. This is actually a provisional always - Your app will not actually receive updates in the background. After some time of your app requesting background location, the user will be prompted to provide "always" permission or keep "when in use".  Once they have responded to that prompt your app will see "always" (if they upgraded) or when in use

From your description, it sounds like your app is actually requesting "always" permission. The code you have shown doesn't seem to do this, but it is always possible that the library you are using isn't doing what you think/want.  Or it is possible that your app is asking for "always" somewhere else.
